# I need a program to create a website like page but it cannot be online at all

Tags: software-recommendation, websites

I am after a program that I can use to create a webpage that will not be online at all, so I can add data like videos, pictures and text and design.

Is there anything available like that? It needs to look like a webpage so you can click and go to different sections etc. Some people have mentioned Powerpoint but the problem with that is that does not automatically update hyperlinks as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

**Kompozer**

Kompozer is a user friendly web designing application. You can design website offline and upload it to the server.

[image: Install via the software center]

Or in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install kompozer
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, so can this be used with just one computer and not uploaded to a server if not needed?

Comment: If you want to host the website by your own computer you need to do some arrangement. You need to install a server application like apache. If you do so, you need to keep the computer online all the time. Otherwise site will be offline when computer is off. Best thing is to host it in a Web host. There are free webhosting services like 000webhost.com.

Comment: I don't need it to be a website. I just need it to look and work like one if possible.The computer will need to be turned off daily. I apologize I'm not very good with computer knowledge, I'm trying to find out for my girlfriend who needs it for work, trying to win some brownie points.

Comment: Ok. So better to install apache server. Instructions are in the below answer.

Comment: don't bother to install apache on your own if you're new to it.. 
if it's only for a local developement rig.. just use xampp instead.. it will install a bunch of stuff for you ..brownie points you will score then with xampp installed..

Comment: cheers.there definitely needed

Comment: I found out it will be on a work server too.

Answer (score 1):

**bluefish**

Bluefish is a GTK+ HTML editor for the experienced web designer. Its features include nice wizards for startup, tables and frames; a fully featured image insert dialog; thumbnail creation and automatically linking of the thumbnail with the original image; and configurable HTML syntax highlighting.

[image: Install via the software center]

Or in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install bluefish
```

It can be used for a local (not online) website.
It can load pages in your browser to see if they render like you want. Both applications do.

But if you want to run a local website without the hassle to install apache and mysql and other stuff you might need along the way I **highly** suggest that you get XAMPP from [here on apachefriends.org](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html)
and follow their instructions to install it. it's quite painless.

Also worth a mention is the new open source editor by adobe called brackets, which you can find more info about [here](http://download.brackets.io/)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need a web server. You can use apache2 which you can install by the command line:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

This will install apache2 making a directory `/var/www` which will be the web root of your offline site.

Now you need an editor to make your website pages. In Ubuntu there are many editor choices:

You can use IDEs such as eclipse and netbeans ...

You can use text editors such as gedit, vim , scribus , if you know how to develop a web page...

If you want specialized editors I advise you to use blue fish

```
sudo apt-get install bluefish
```

If you want some wysiwyg editors you can use:

**1. Kompozer**

```
sudo apt-get install kompozer
```

[**2. bluegriffon**](http://bluegriffon.org/pages/Download)

When you finish your web pages move the working directory to `/var/www/`

then you can access from your browser:

```
http://your-ip/Working-directory
```

Comment: you have a typo in the apache2 install..

Comment: @marc-andrebenoit i corrected it... thanks :)